# How to evaluate the xgboost classification model stability

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, gradient-descent, supervised-learning

I have:

1. Python xgboost classification model
2. Weekly datasets (basis of classification) since the begining of 2018. Each of dataset has about 100 thousand rows and 70 columns (features).
3. weekly prediction results on datasets via xgboost model (using logistic regression) in the format:

```
- date of modelling
- items
- test_auc_mean for each item (in percentage).
```

In total there are about 100 datasets and 100 prediction_results since January 2018.

To assess the model I use such metrics as:

-auc

-confusion matrix

-accuracy

```
param = {
    'num_parallel_tree':num_parallel_tree,
    'subsample':subsample,
    'colsample_bytree':colsample_bytree,
    'objective':objective, 
    'learning_rate':learning_rate, 
    'eval_metric':eval_metric, 
    'max_depth':max_depth,
    'scale_pos_weight':scale_pos_weight,
    'min_child_weight':min_child_weight,
    'nthread':nthread,
    'seed':seed
}

bst_cv = xgb.cv(
    param, 
    dtrain,  
    num_boost_round=n_estimators, 
    nfold = nfold,
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    verbose_eval=verbose,
    stratified = stratified
)

test_auc_mean = bst_cv['test-auc-mean']
best_iteration = test_auc_mean[test_auc_mean == max(test_auc_mean)].index[0]

bst = xgb.train(param, 
                dtrain, 
                num_boost_round = best_iteration)

best_train_auc_mean = bst_cv['train-auc-mean'][best_iteration]
best_train_auc_mean_std = bst_cv['train-auc-std'][best_iteration]

best_test_auc_mean = bst_cv['test-auc-mean'][best_iteration]
best_test_auc_mean_std = bst_cv['test-auc-std'][best_iteration]

print('''XGB CV model report
Best train-auc-mean {}% (std: {}%) 
Best test-auc-mean {}% (std: {}%)'''.format(round(best_train_auc_mean * 100, 2), 
                                          round(best_train_auc_mean_std * 100, 2), 
                                          round(best_test_auc_mean * 100, 2), 
                                          round(best_test_auc_mean_std * 100, 2)))

y_pred = bst.predict(dtest)
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred>0.9).ravel()


print('''
     | neg | pos |
__________________
true_| {}  | {}  |
false| {}  | {}  |
__________________

'''.format(tn, tp, fn, fp))

predict_accuracy_on_test_set = (tn + tp)/(tn + fp + fn + tp)
print('Test Accuracy: {}%'.format(round(predict_accuracy_on_test_set * 100, 2)))
```

The model gives me general picture (as usually, auc is between .94 and .96)
The problem is that the variability of predicting of some specific items is very high (today an item is positive, tomorrow an item is negative, the day after tomorrow - positive again)

I wanna evaluate the model' stability. In other words, I wanna know, how many items with variable results does it generate. In the end, I wanna be ensured, that the model will generate stable results with minimal fluctuation.
Do you have some thoughts how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's precisely the goal of cross validation. Since you already did it, you can only evaluate standard deviation of your evaluation metrics, you already did it aswell...

1. You can try some new metrics, like precision,recall,f1 score or fn score to weight success and failure differently but it looks like your almost out of solutions. You're dependant to your data input here :s
2. You could spend some time on training population distribution, and try to identify which part of the population fluctuate over time.
3. You could also try to predict proba and not classification to evaluate if the model is far above its threshold or not.

The last two solution are more like side solutions. :(

Comment: Gwendal, thank you. Will the other metrics help, if the dataset' size is big (100 thousand rows)? I think, even if I use cross-validation, it will take thousands of rows in each fold and it will level fluctuation. May be, there is some method, to measure variability of eash of items, 1 by 1 and, then, to calculate the percentage of those, which doesn't fit to requirements. The other question is: what requirements to stability I should set: may be, number of unexpected peaks, or changes' intensity, or changes' frequency...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Predict-proba of 1 item (mean-auc]
Gwendal, thank you. 
Would you specify 2 approaches you mentioned. 
1) how can I train population distribution? via K-Clustering or other methods of unsupervised learning? 
2) E.g. I predicted_proba (the diagram of 1 specific item - is in the attachement). How can I evaluate if the model is far above its threshold? Via comparison predicted_proba of each item with it's true label (e.g. predict_proba = 0.5 and label = 1)?

Comment: First approache :

Population distribution is more about statistical analysis than ML. You could evaluate each feature distribution in your initial dataset. If some distributions shows some low represented values for a feature, you can assume (it is a possibility not a truth) that these low represented values can be in you next test set. If these low represented values happened again your model(s) will have some variation in perf. Otherwise if distibution si quite even you can assume your model will keep it's perf :)

Comment: Second Approach : For binary classification, without any parameter tuning, threshold is indeed at 0.5.

I'm not sure about multi class, if it just goes for the best one amongs classes. If it's like that you could basically make the diff between first proba (actual class predicted) and second one. If diff is quite small, you have chance that in next predictions you predicted class will change :)

Comment: Comment about your graph : You currently display the proba of the current predicted class right? (you're supposed to have proba for each target class) If it's right, are you sure this class was predicted every time (best proba each time)? You could compute std for each item, which mean, for each item you could get a KPI showing the prob fluctuation which is what you want right ? :) You could do the same computation for diff between awarded class and second one.With these 2 metrics you could indeed evaluate consistency of you model(s).

Comment: Second Approach: what are actual class predicted and second class predicted? I have a data set for model training  (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test). I also have unlabeled data, which I apply to model and count predict_proba.

Comment: Comment about graph : I displayed proba of one of thousands items in the dataset. Should I calculate the mean of all items proba to get a proba for the target class? I have proba as a result of using the usual classifier, not cross validation. To get std for each Item, should I use CV or simply use the values for different days?

Comment: Second Approach : 

predict_proba method of a classification model returns the "confidence" of the model to return a class. It returns an array for each output class.

Awarded and second, are first and second "confidence" within the predict_proba result array.

Comment: Comment about graph : 

CV does not support prediction/prob_prediction for each item. So you can analyse STD of a global metric (all available in sklearn) **over cv results**.

Then for your current model, you can analyse **over time** the std of the predicted proba for the first class(first class ranked by proba, which award the classif) and the diff between first and second.

Comment: Gwendal, thank you. Second Approach :  If my threshold is .9 (i.e, all predicted probas, which are above .9 - are '1s' and under - are '0s', can I apply this method?

Comment: Your model can indeed behave like that. But it can reduce your perf, the model can be too "scared" to predict success target.